# Union of collection of sets in vector

Tags: arrays, vector, julia, union

If I have a vector of sets, say,

```
vec_of_sets = [Set(vec1), Set(vec2), ..., Set(vecp)]
```

how do I obtain a set equal to the union of sets in the vector? That is, how can I write the following efficiently?

```
S1 = Set(vec1);
union!(S1, Set(vec2))
union!(S1, Set(vec3))
...
union!(S1, Set(vecp))
```

I don't really know where to start!

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: I have tried a solution using generating functions but it doesn't work:

```
union(j for j in vec_of_sets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and fastest approach is:

```
Set(Iterators.flatten(vec_of_sets))
```

It is around twice as fast as other possible approaches proposed at the other post and has makes than half memory allocations.

Here are some benchmarks:

```
julia> v = [Set(1:3), Set(2:6), Set(4:8)];

julia> @btime Set(Iterators.flatten($v));
  270.492 ns (4 allocations: 400 bytes)

julia> @btime reduce(union, $v);
  550.000 ns (11 allocations: 1.25 KiB)

julia> @btime union($v...);
  506.250 ns (11 allocations: 944 bytes)

julia> @btime union((j for j in $v)...);
  699.286 ns (15 allocations: 1.03 KiB)
```

Comment: "best" is subjective ;) Also what about "in-place" `reduce(union!, v)`? (I did not put in my answer because it mutates `v[1]` but it's allocation-free, right?)

Comment: `reduce(union!, v)` is actually better :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use `reduce`:

```
reduce(union, vec_of_sets)
```

but you could also use splatting (with `...`):

```
union(vec_of_sets...)
```

FWIW, you could have used splitting with your attempt, too:

```
union((j for j in vec_of_sets)...)
```